# QGridLayout and QVBoxLayout don't auto expand spacing

Tags: pyqt4

So if I have two elements in a fixed size window to start with, instead of staying at their `layoutVerticalSpacing`, the elements auto expand the vertical spaces as I resize the main window.

I've tried `self.gridLayout.setVerticalSpacing(0)` but that doesn't quite work...

Is there a way to just set the spacing to stay the same no matter what the mainWindow size is?

Comment: Put an expanding vertical spacer below the widgets.

Comment: That did the job, thank you!